# issue with a specific graphic card

Tags: rendering

I recently built a new PC for graphic purpose and Blender use. I bought an ATI 7990. Unfortunately Blender do not see it and the rendering menu.

It's a "old" graphic card but it's still very powerful. I checked it's architecture and pilot and as mush as I can say, it should be compatible, but it's not...

Can anyone give me some tips about it? Would be awesome!

Thanks guys, speak soon :))

Comment: Did you enabled it under user preferences ?

Comment: Hi! Can't enable it in preferences as it doesn't appear at all... :/